# scipy.optimize.basinhopping. Object function with argument(s)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So, I have a function f=(x,a,b), which I want to minimize using  scipy.optimize.basinhopping. x - is the variable I'm optimizing over and a,b are parameters. It's not really clear how to pass values of a,b to the object function. Or this is not possible? For example, in scipy.optimize.minimize there is a special parameter "args" for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's unclear about the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html)?

> func : callable f(x, *args)
>
> Function to be optimized. args can be passed as an optional item in the dict minimizer_kwargs

...

> See also **minimize**
>
> The local minimization function called once for each basinhopping step. minimizer_kwargs is passed to this routine.

So it's somewhat like:

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"args": (a, b)}
ret = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
```